# "You have already authorized" Facebook page

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

Yes, I too facing the same problem,I'm getting a page with message"You have already authorized"  when I press the "sign in via facebook" in mjyandroid app, but it works fine for other users, Only for me(i am facing the issue). Can u tell me , how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, it looks like -every- of our users have that same behavior on our iOS apps. This started as a few users mentioning the change in behavior to a much larger (all?) users seeing this.
Apparently, this is the new FB app authorization workflow and seem to only affect those apps that go through an inline login form (I.e. older FB SDK) or those that goes through the Safari browser (again... My only experience is on the iOS side).
Please log this as a defect on the Fb bug tracking site.